# Limit of function , neighbourhood

Tags: real-analysis

If limit as x approaches 0 of  `f(x)+f(2x)---(*)` is 0 . Does this imply that f has limit at 0?
Prove that if there is a function g such that in a deleted neighborhood of 0 the inequality f(x)>(=) g(x) is satisfied and limit as x approaches 0 g(x)=0 then

```
To show (*) implies,  limit as x approaches to 0 of f(x) is 0
```

My approach:- g(x) <= f(x) = f(x)+f(2x)-f(2x) <= f(x) + f(2x) -g(2x) 
Implies limit of f(x) as x approaches 0 is 0 .

Comment: It is not true that if $f(x)\ge g(x)$ and $g(x) \to 0$ then $f(x) \to 0$.

Comment: What is the counter example

Comment: EG $g(x)=x$ and $f(x)=1+x$, maybe I'm loosing something in your statement, otherwise you should revise that

Comment: Your function does not satisfy equation * . Read the question carefully

Comment: Sorry, please clarify better what are the hypoteses and what you need to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explicit counterexample is $f(x)=[\sin (\pi\log_{2} x)]$, where $[\cdot ]$ is the nearest integer function. To see that $\lim_{x\to0} f(x)+f(2x)=0$, note that

$$\begin{aligned}f(x)+f(2x)&=[\sin (\pi\log_{2} x)]+[\sin (\pi\log_{2} (2x))]
\\
&=[\sin (\pi\log_{2} x)]+[-\sin (\pi\log_{2} x )]
\\
&=0
\end{aligned}$$

However, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f(2^{-n})$ is identically $0$ yet $f(2^{-(n+1/2)})=\pm1$, so $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: In case both sides of the limit are desired, simply take $f|x|$. Furthermore, without loss of generality, $f_a(x)=[\sin(\pi \log_a x)]$ shows that for *any* $a\in\mathbb{R}^+/\{1\}$, $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)+f(ax)=0$ need not imply $\lim f(x)=0$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let consider the function $g(x)=n\in \mathbb N$ such that $\forall x\in[-2,2]$ and $y\in\mathbb R$ we have $x=\frac {y}{2^n}$ and the function $f:[-1,1]\to \{-1,1\}$ such that $f\left(x\right)=(-1)^{g(x)}$ therefore

$$f(2x)+f(x)=0$$

but

$$\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$$

doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah , the counter example seems to be fine , what about the other part of the question , what ever argument I made over there is correct ?!

Comment: @OmPrakash I don't understand what is exactly the point for the second part. What are you trying to prove with that?

Comment: @OmPrakash I need to fix something with the definition for f but the idea is clear I think.

Comment: @user I don't quite understand the definition of $f$. It seems we are solving for $n$ when given $x$ but what are the constraints on $y$? If $x=\frac1{\pi}$, would we have $n=0,y=\frac{1}{\pi}$ or $n=1,y=\frac2\pi$?

Comment: @Jam Yes I've changed something now. I'm considering a bijection from $y\in \mathbb R \to \forall x\in[-2,2]$ such that $x=\frac {y}{2^n}$ in that way we can associate at any $x\in[-2,2]$ a natural number $n$, that is $g(x)=n$.

Comment: @Jam Please let me know if that definition can be improved to be more clear.

Comment: @user Just letting you know I found an explicit function that satisfies what we were looking for.